# Could the result of several variables be assigned to another variable in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I just started learning Shiny not long ago. I want to assign **y** to **(y1+y2+y3+y4)/4**, and call this assigned **y** in other places.

At first I tried the simple definition
`y=(input$y1+input$y2+input$y3+input$y4)/4`, but it doesn’t work. I also tried many other methods, but they also didn't work.

Because I will use **y** many times in the subsequent calculations (such as calculating variance), but each time I use `(input$y1+input$y2+input$y3+input$y4)/4` will be very bloated (**yi**, **i** may Will be more than 20)

Part of my code is as follows,

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
numericInput("y1", "y1:", sample(1:200,1), min = 1, max = 200)),
numericInput("y2", "y2:", sample(1:200,1), min = 1, max = 200)),
numericInput("y3", "y3:", sample(1:200,1), min = 1, max = 200)),
numericInput("y4", "y4:", sample(1:200,1), min = 1, max = 200))
))
```

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$y <- renderText({(input$y1+input$y2+input$y3+input$y4)/4})
})
```

I don't know if there is a suitable solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own reactive value from the input

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  y <- reactive((input$y1+input$y2+input$y3+input$y4)/4)

  output$y <- renderText(y())

})
```

You you create a reactive value, you call it like a function `y()` rather than a variable `y` to get it's current value

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I was troubled with it for many hours.